# What does the AT+CWDHCP? return?

Tags: at-command, esp8266

what does the AT+CWDHCP? command return? I tried running this command but its return some number. i tried to find it out but could not find anywhere.can anyone one help me in solving this?

Comment: Your search engine didn't return the multiple results for this exact command for this exact product? Try another one then.

Answer (score 1):

> what does the AT+CWDHCP? command return?

The (current) documentation

http://espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/4a-esp8266_at_instruction_set_en.pdf

states

> 4.2.14. AT+CWDHCP—Enables/Disables DHCP
>
> [@deprecated] **This command is deprecated**.
>
> Please use AT+CWDHCP_CUR or AT+CWDHCP_DEF instead.

You did not state which firmware version you are working with, so this may not be applicable. But the return value is described as

```
Returns: DHCP disabled or enabled now? 
Parameters
* Bit0:
  - 0: Station DHCP is disabled.
  - 1: Station DHCP is enabled.
* Bit1:
  - 0: SoftAP DHCP is disabled.
  - 1: SoftAP DHCP is enabled
```

So, decoding those bits, the decimal return values should represent these states:

- 0 "SoftAP DHCP is disabled" and "Station DHCP is disabled"
- 1 "SoftAP DHCP is disabled" and "Station DHCP is **enabled**"
- 2 "SoftAP DHCP is disabled" and "Station DHCP is disabled"
- 3 "SoftAP DHCP is **enabled**" and "Station DHCP is **enabled**"